# How can I proxy a GraphQL request from my Node.js app in an efficient way?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, proxy, axios, graphql

My current setup for the project I'm working on is:

- Next.js
- Wordpress backend with GraphQL plugin enabled
- They live on two different servers

I would like to be able to make a request from a Next.js page that proxy via an api-route to the Wordpress backend. I want the GraphQL query to be passed along and I would like to be able to modify the request (for example add header, set a cookie etc) before it reaches the Wordpress backend.

I first tried to achieve this using this module: https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy and using the `.web()` request. It almost worked except I got back a response from Wordpress that I wasn't able to decode (tried with Buffer etc, but no success).

So my current way to do this is to make an `axios`-request from my api route and pass along the `req.body` in that request, and that setup works.

However, is this way to proxy OK or should I try to make it work with `node-http-proxy`? Don't know about what possible benefits there are.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `Axios` you will make an extra request when you retrieve data from the source. This will decrease performance. On the other side if you use proxy you will forward the incoming request and this way you will have improved performance.

Comment: I see. Would you be able to help me out with an example on how to proxy the request?

Comment: I haven’t used it, maybe you could try the example npm package